# How to use 'git fetch' in different places?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Im try to use Git on the work and home (for example project name - "sample"). I use `add push -u origin master` for upload my changes on github, then I come to home and try to renew my project with command `git fetch` and got a NEW sample directory in my sample directory. When I try smth like `cd .. && git fetch sample` - I got an error that directory is not empty. How I can to update my project on work and home everyday? Im new in git, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a `git fetch` and `git pull` should be sufficient, after stashing any changes you want to keep in your current working branch (`master` in your case).

If you are able to execute `git fetch` when you are already in `sample`, and that resulted in another `sample` directory nested in the current directory, it probably means you have checked in your entire project directory as a new subdirectory by accident.

Comment: All the answers are good but I'm guessing that what @prusswan said, about accidentally checking in the entire project directory, instead of just the contents, is actually the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen 3 times the same answer in less than a minute since I arrived on that topic, so just for the sake of diversity : `merge` and `pull` aren't the only options!

You should also have a look at `git rebase` which has the advantage (imho) to keep your tree more readable (because more linear).
It also have a really useful interactive mode, which every git user should know how to use.
So you might as well start looking at it now.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `git pull` instead. It does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. Also make sure you are in the right folder when calling the git command.

Comment: really worked for me next steps: 
git add .
git commit -m "nice"
git pull origin master
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error that directory is not empty.

I can't understand that error, but let me be silly and ask, did you clone your project on your home machine and you are commanding `git fetch` from inside the right directory!?

I think [gitref.org](http://gitref.org) will help you to deal with basic tasks in git.

Comment: added to my favorites, really I copied that with my USB flash and now try to use git )